# Return multiple DataFrames from a function with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to parse multiple excel sheets with Pandas into separate individual DataFrames.

My code so far is:

```
sheet_names =[tab1, tab2]
df_names = [1,2]

def initilize_dataframes(sheet_names):
    for name in sheet_names:
       df = xls_file.parse(name) #parse the xlxs sheet
       df = df.transpose() #transpose dates to index
       new_header = df.iloc[0] #column header names 
       df = df[1:] #drop 1st row 
       df.rename(columns=new_header, inplace= True) #rename the columns
    return df`
`
for i in df_names:
     df_(i) = initilize_dataframes(sheet_names)#something like this idk
```

The last two lines I can not wrap my head around. I get that the function will return the df, but I would like it to take the values from the df_names list. And label the DataFrame accordingly.

For example, tab1 in the excel sheet the DataFrame should be named df_1 and looping for tab2 and df_2 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by `globals`:

```
for i, val in enumerate(df_names):
     globals()['df_' + str(vals)] = initilize_dataframes(sheet_names[i])
```

But better is use `dict` of `DataFrames`,  `sheet_names` select by positions from `enumerate`, but need substract `1`, because python counts from `0`:

```
dfs = {}
for i, val in enumerate(df_names):
     dfs[val] = initilize_dataframes(sheet_names[i])

print (dfs[1])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you ! and the dictionary was something i hadn't even considered. Brilliant.

Comment: @KKobain - Glad can help!

Comment: What if my DataFrames are not integers, but rather 
`df_names= ['sheet1','sheet2','sheet3']`

Comment: And then select by `print (dfs['sheet1'])`

Comment: Now its not working ? its showing this error `raise XLRDError('No sheet named <%r>' % sheet_name)

XLRDError: No sheet named <'t'>` so it doesnt seem to be iterating correctly. Is there something wrong with the initial definition ?

Comment: It seems some excel problem, it seems you want seelct some sheet with different name.

Comment: Got it going, not sure exactly of the reasoning, but instead of the
`sheet_names[i-1]` 
I replaced with the slice 
`sheet_names[i:]`
so that i would be the selected starting value, run the function for that slice, exit, and move to the next i . ??

Comment: Yes, you are right, is necessary `sheet_names[i]` not `sheet_names[i-1]`, because enumerate counts from 0 (I think it counts from1)